# Holiday deductions on leaving job

Tags: employment

## Background

I'm based in the UK and I am working my final week before I start my new job in a different organisation. I am in deficit of 14 days holiday and I've just received my final payslip.

I work Monday to Friday, 37 hours a week, 7.4 hours a day. My last day is the 27th March.

### Problem

My final salary is a lot less than I expected, they have deducted ¾ of my pay so I am left with only ¼.

The following are calculations that were used to work out my last pay.

### Calculations for how much I owe for holiday pay

- Hourly Rate = Annual Pay / 52 / 37
- Daily Rate = Hourly Rate x 7.4
- Holiday Cost = Daily Rate x 14

### Calculation for how much I get on my last Month (March)

- Base Pay = Annual Pay / 12 / 31 x 27
- Gross Pay = Base Pay – Holiday Cost

### Question

Are the calculations they have provided correct?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe they're not correct?

Comment: Does your company have staff that work nights or weekends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two issues with the calculation in your question.

- Is the 14 days holiday 14 working days (or almost 3 weeks) or is it 2 weeks and therefore 10 work days?
- the calculation uses work days when figuring the holiday cost, but then the last set of calculations uses percent of calendar days when calculating the base pay.

My calculation would be you worked 20 days (2-6, 9-13, 16-20, 23-27) you owe them 14 days of holiday pay. meaning they should pay you for 6 days (20 minus 14). That would mean you would get 30% (6/20) of your pay, before taxes or any other deductions.

Comment: It is a total of 14 working days. I'm definitely getting short changed but it will be interesting to find out how my flexi credit will be applied; for example will it be at the daily rate or the lower monthly percentage.